# ffmpeg audio encoding based on codec and not on stream identifier

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have an RTSP Stream with one video stream and three audio streams as the source. Two of the audio streams are encoded with `.mp2` and one is encoded with `.ac-3`. I want to convert the `.mp2` streams to AAC. This would be easy if the `.mp2`streams would have the same stream identifier every time I start ffmpeg, but unfortunately the stream identifiers change. This means sometimes the two `.mp2` streams are **0:a:0** and **0:a:1** and the next time they are **0:a:1** and **0:a:2**.

Is there an option to re-encode only the `.mp2` streams and keep the `.ac-3` stream untouched?
I should probably also mention that this encoding is used for live TV so it is not an option to produce intermediate files or have several ffmpeg commands.

Comment: is there any stream metadata that you can take advantage of to distinguish these streams?

Comment: All three have the same language, but one of the .mp2 streams is marked with "(visual impaired) (descriptions)"

Comment: Those are dispositions (and likely not listed under metadata (tags). See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ffprobe -show_entries stream_tags -select_streams a INPUT_URL
```

and see if there are any stream tags (metadata) that distinguishes mp2 streams. Then you can use the metadata stream specifier to selectively set re-encoding:

```
ffmpeg ... -c copy -c:a:m:{name}:{value} ac3 ...
```

where `{name}` and `{value}` are the name and value of the tag, respectively.

Reference on stream specifier: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1

If there isn't any usable tag, your only solution likely is to run `ffprobe` first to identify the stream # before running `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately there are no usable tags and if I run ffprobe twice in a very short time the stream numbers change as well. ffmpeg must be assigning them randomly each time.

Comment: Do you have the control over the input RTSP stream as well? If so, can you hardcode the audio stream order by `-map` options?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. The stream originates from a SAT>IP server I have no control over.

Comment: I found out that there is the PID in .TS files, which could probably be useful. Is there an option in ffprobe to output it? VLC shows it when inspecting the codecdetails of a running stream.